# Sending email from 2010 workflow in 2013to user granted access through Active Directory group

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, active-directory, email

In SharePoint 2013 on-premise, I have ListA, and grant Active Directory group GroupA Contribute rights to it. I assign a 2010 workflow to the list which should send an email to the person who created the item (or to anyone in GroupA for that matter). The workflow starts and completes without any errors (logging to Workflow History) but the email does not send. If I grant the user permission directly to the list then the email does send. I have 2000+ users so this is not a viable solution.

I do not see any recognizable error logs but I may not be looking in the right places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the Send Mail activity inside the **impersonation step** for 2010 designer workflows which will give elevated privilege to run the workflow actions.
Check this : https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Workflow-conditions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. The email was sending but was always going to the Junk Mail folder. 
Maureen